# Using Abstract class for Junit + WebDriver automated tests

Tags: junit, automated-tests, webdriver, abstract-class

I have a question about automation tests.

I need to test search for different languages (French, German etc)

All test methods are same so I don't want to duplicate code. Just search queries are different

What is the best practice to implement it.

If you have experience how to do this it will be very helpful if you give me some little examples

Comment: I use Parameterized Tests but I think that's quite ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Seperate layout from the content language with cannonical element naming for Id, class, attributes.
2. If you have no control of the target web site use Properties files

   - english.element-name.xpath=
   - french.element-name.xpath=
   - german.element-name.xpath=
3. Use the built in Java localisation support e.g.

   - ResourceBundle.getBundle("GuiMapBundle", targetLocale);
4. Use Polymorphism e.g.

   - EnglishSite extends SiteNavigation
   - FrenchSite extends SiteNavigation
   - GermanSite extends SiteNavigation